# Removing space(s) from the end of a filename

Tags: regex, perl

I've got a variables such as the following:

```
$str1 = 'some random book cover  .jpg';
$str2 = 'some random cd cover .jpg';
```

where I'd like to remove the leading spaces before the period in the file extension so the above examples should look like:

```
$str1 = 'some random book cover.jpg';
$str2 = 'some random cd cover.jpg';
```

There may be any number of spaces there. I can (and did after floundering with the regexp) write a kludgy little subroutine in perl to do this, but this seems like something that'd be custom made a regexp expression. Unfortunatley my regexp-fu abilities are lacking.

Could somebody show me the error of my ways and ease my troubled mind?

Answer (score 5):

```
$subject =~ 
    s/\s+   # Match one or more spaces
    (?=     # if they are followed by
     \.     # a dot
     [^.]*  # and any number of characters except dots
     $      # up to the end of the string.
    )
    //xg;
```

should do it, assuming you're looking for any kind of file extension, not just `jpg`.

`(?=...)` is a so-called [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which ascertains that the enclosed could be matched at the current position, but doesn't include it in the match result.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I was looking for! And yes, I've got any number of file extensions to deal with. I wasn't aware of the "?=" before... back to reading for me. Many thanks!

Comment: There is a website to analyse regular expression like this if I remember it properly. Could you give me the link?

Comment: @Shiplu: I don't know about a website. I just know about (and use) [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Greedy matching solution:

```
s/^(.*\S)\s+\./$1./
```